# Memory allocation for regular class static class static method instanve method and data member on heap and stack c#?

Tags: c#, oop

Most of the book never talk about how a program execute and how memory is allocated for them on stack and heap. when data stored on stack and when on heap.

Suppose i have one regular class like

```
public class MyClass
{
    int Age=0;
    string strName="None"
    Double Salary=0;

    public void Data1()
    {
        Age=30;
        strName="Robin";
        Salary=3500;
    }
}
```

### Question

1) so for the above class how memory will be allocated. when program run the memory will be allocated or when we create instance then memory will be allocated. when we call `Data1()` through instance then what happen and how memory will be allocated. memory will be allocated for function call or for data member initialization? tell me how much memory will be allocated for `age`, `name` and `salary`. memory will be allocated on stack or heap.

```
public class MyClass
{
    static int y=0; 
    static string strComp="None"
    int Age=0;
    string strName="None"
    Double Salary=0;

    public void Data1()
    {
        Age=30;
        strName="Robin";
        Salary=3500;
    }

    public static void Data3()
    {
         y=50;
         strComp="Hello";
    }
}
```

2) how and when memory is allocated for static data member and function. when we call like
`MyClass.Data3()` then memory will be allocated or when we just run the apps. memory is allocated on heap or stack?

3) how memroy is allocated for static class. static class stored on heap or stack...if stack then why?

here i asked asked couple of question please explain in detail. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.) Memory will be allocated when you create an instance of the class. When you call `Data1()` no additional memory is needed as you are only referencing fields of the class instance (and no other local variables). Since `MyClass` is a reference type, memory will be allocated on the managed heap.

2.) Static methods do not consume any memory. Static fields are initialized before you access any static field or create any instance of the type they are contained in (`MyClass` in this case)

3.) You cannot create an instance of a static class so no memory is allocated dynamically, only when the type itself is created. Static classes are guaranteed to be loaded and to have their fields initialized and their static constructor called before the class is referenced for the first time in your program. Once created a static class remains in memory until your application domain is shut down.

Comment: few things not clear from your explanation. 1) i just need to memory is allocated for function separately and data member separately when function called like instacename.funcname()? 2) memory is allocated for static function just before when we first time create a instance of the class? 3) how memory is allocated for static class when we first time refer the class like mystaticclass.staticfunction()? am i right and if not then please discuss again.

Comment: @user: methods/functions do not consume any memory, only "data" does

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a class instance is created only when you actually create one with the new() directive.

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
```

Only when a new instance is created the memory is allocated, including all of the object's fields.

Static members don't belong to an object instance of the class.
You can think of it this way: The class itself has one object that represents the actual class type, and all the static members and methods belong to that object. (It isn't actually like this, but it's easier to understand the static concept this way)
The static class members are created at the beginning of the program (or when the dll is first loaded).

when you create a new object with new() it is created in the heap (along with all its members).

Variables that are created in the stack belong methods in the runtime environment and only after you access the block in which they are declared.

Comment: memory is allocated for function or for data member? when we create instance then memory is allocated for all the function if class has 5 function or just on demand when function is invoked.

Comment: When you create a new instance of a class, the memory is allocated for that instance with all its members (as defined in the class). Method (function) local variables are only allocated when the method is invoked.