# C# memory allocation: Difference between static class and a static instance

Tags: c#, memory-management, static, compact-framework, instance

How does CLR allocates memory in these 2 cases: 
Are they both allocated in static memory area?

```
static class A 
{
    //Some methods
}
```

**and**

```
class A 
{
    //Some methods    
}
class B
{
    static A inst = new A();
    //Some methods
}
```

For the below statement, will the compiler

```
static A inst = new A();
```

allocate *A* in heap and assign it to static reference *inst* reference?
**Or**
it will create a static instance in ***High Frequency heap***?

Comment: duplicate ???? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719126/memory-allocation-for-regular-class-static-class-static-method-instanve-method-a

Comment: Thanks @Freelancer, but the Link you attached is similar but doesn't answer my query.

Answer (score 0):

Static fields are as any static fields, regardless if the class is static or non-static.

A static class is just a tric from C# to ensure that all members are static, nothing more. In .NET static classes do not even exists: A C# static class will be converted into a .NET instance class with a private instance constructor. That way an instance of that class cannot be constructed.

Comment: You say static classes don't exist and then you proceed to explain how they exist. If a static class exists in memory, if it's data and methods exist in memory, then it truly does exist. It's not a trick. Indeed, you have helped me understand how we can in fact have a reference to a static class, which the language does not currently expose. And many people say it's impossible, often citing that since they can't be instantiated, there can't have a reference to it. Of course, we don't have to instantiate it to get a ref - but that's getting onto another subject.

Comment: @GavinWilliams: I edited my answer to make it more clear.